# Checkbox add elements to array

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm seem having problem with inserting an element to an array.
What I'm trying to do is if the CheckBox is tick it would insert an element in the array and if the checkbox is unticked remove the element from the array

```
package src
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{   
    var positionY:Number = 80;
    var positionX:Number = 0;
    var motion:MovieClip;
    var fCombo:Array = new Array();
    var n:Number;
    var combo:Array = new Array();

public function Main()
{
    Basic.selected = true;
    Basic.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, change);
    generate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, loop); 
    generate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, remove); 
    n = Number(inputText.text);
    var combo:Array = [];
}
function loop(me:MouseEvent):void
{


    var combo:Array = [Punch, Kick, Knee, Elbow];
    n = Number(inputText.text);
    for(var i:Number = 0;i < n;i++ )
        {
        motion = new combo[randomNumber(combo.length)]();  
        fCombo.push(motion);
        motion.y = positionY;
        motion.x = positionX;
        positionX += 100;
        addChild(motion);
        if (i == 4 || i == 9 || i == 14 || i == 19)
                {
                    positionY += 40;
                    positionX = 0;
                }
        }
}
function remove(me:MouseEvent):void
{
    var k:Number = n
 while(fCombo.length)
{
    removeChild(fCombo.pop());
}
    positionY = 80;
    positionX = 0;
}

function randomNumber(max:Number):Number
    {
    return(Math.floor(Math.random() * max ));
    }


function change(e:Event):void
{
    if (Basic == true)
    {
        combo.push(UpperCut); //this movieclip won't insert inside the array
    }
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Basic is a checkBox, So

```
if (Basic == true)
{
    combo.push(UpperCut); //this movieclip won't insert inside the array
}
```

Should be

```
if (Basic.selected == true)
{
    combo.push(UpperCut); //this movieclip won't insert inside the array
}
```